# Is it sufficient to wash utensils, which have touched chicken, with soapy water

Tags: food-safety, bacteria

In the kitchen, I am very health conscious and try to prepare and store foods with care

After working with a whole chicken, I usually wash the chopping board and knife with hot (but not boiling) soapy water (in particular, the dish soap I use is Fairy Liquid)

But, is this actually sufficient in killing all the unwanted germs and/or bacteria? I've seen maybe 1 article and people on forums stating that you should use bleach instead - is this necessary?

Comment: Although not specifically off topic here, food safety questions are the domain of the Cooking exchange. You will get much better answers there.

Comment: It's extremely difficult to sterilize a kitchen after handling raw chicken as e coli gets everywhere. Studies have been done in this area.

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1365-2672.2008.03778.x/full